# How to use a string variable in Python in Java?

Tags: java, python-3.x, import, var, cross-language

Let's say I have a variable in Python called test_text and is equal to "hello"
I want to be able to use that inside a separate Java file using `System.out.println(text_test);`

I have worked with Java and Python both but not together.
I am not sure where to start, I have heard of JPython though, but I would like opinions for my specific request.

Python:

```
test = "hello"
```

Java:

```
System.out.println(test);
```

Thank you! I need to send data from a Python script to a Java file.'

OR:

Suggest a good language to create a GUI application with good support for Python

Comment: Depending on the application requirements, you can use any of the integration patterns https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big of a system you are working on, you might consider a messaging queue like RabbitMQ.

You would send messages between a [Python](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) and [Java](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html), and do actions in one of them whenever there are messages available.

You can also go to a lower level and work with something like Redis (in-memory DB), [like this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43698292/604048).

Yet, another alternative is to communicate between them as micro services. Where each one exposes an API, say, standard http restful API. On the Python side I'd go for [Flask-RESTPlus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but on the Java side I'm unsure, some time since I used it last.

Comment: So there isn't a simple way to do this? Is it easier with other languages? I know it sounds like I'm trying to find an easy way out, but I want to learn Python but another one that works well with it. I have a 1300 line Python application, but want a new language.